# Input/output error on /etc/shadow

Tags: filesystem, password, files

the file /etc/shadow seems to be corrupted as every time I try to remove it throws an input/output error. Now this is a problem because it contains my passwords and I get login without it. Anyone now how to fix this or an alternative way to get me logged in? Right now I can access the filesystem off of a Ubuntu live cd

EDIT: I fixed it by running e2fsck -y -v -f /dev/device. Will answer when I can

Comment: NOTE: A `fsck` won't always solve an Input/Output problem - you should always look into what could cause this to make sure that there's nothing else MORE broken.

Comment: This seemed to solve it because all is seems to be normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This answer is based on an edit by the user to their own question.  They should still answer when they can.

Run an `e2fsck -v /dev/device` (replace `/dev/device` with the actual device path), and it can probably fix the issue.

Comment: Change it to add the params because when I ran it like that it said it was clean

Comment: @TameHog There should be an 'edit' button you can click and can propose edits yourself.

Comment: Problem is sometimes it doesn't get approved

Comment: @TameHog that's not a concern at the moment. The owner of the answer gets a notice about the edit request, since I'm actually ONLINE you can propose the edit; whether it's accepted is determined by the rules and guidelines for editing. Since I"m the owner of the question and I basically just quoted you, and you never provided any additional arguments above in your edit, I did a pretty much verbatim copy/paste. As well, *all* < 2k users have the risk of edits being disapproved - until you edit and propose the edit nobody can say whether it's good or not, and you can see why it was rejected too.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's my bad

Comment: @TameHog neither `-f` nor `-y` should be used unless you **know** they are needed - you may end up causing more harm than good.

Comment: I knew that I needed -f -y, I tried other params but the filesystem was never fixed @muru